# Is the nominal voltage of a motor the voltage to apply to the motor?

Tags: motor, brushless-motor

I have just sized the DC motors I want to use (corresponding to my robot and its intended applications - my figures include a 50% uncertainty factor to account for friction in reducers and other losses). Now I need to actually choose the exact motors I want to buy from the manufacturer (I am targeting maxon motors as I am not an expert and want no problem). I have a few down to earth questions about linking the mechanical needs to the electrical characteristics, among them:

**Question #1:**

Maxon (or the other manufacturers) states a "nominal voltage" in the characteristic sheets. Is that the voltage you should apply to the motor? This may be a dumb question but I have followed the full maxon e-learning course and read about other tutorials on the web and I could not find this information anywhere. Can anyone who knows about motors confirm?

I have followed some theoretical and practical courses on the web but I find it hard to find answers to my down to earth question...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To control the power of a DC motor you control the voltage applied to it. So no, it's not the "only" voltage you can apply to the motor. The nominal value is a reference so we know what to what specs the motor was engineered. You can input more than the nominal voltage to get more power but it may for example get a bit hotter than it is supposed to, as it wasn't designed to work continuously at a higher voltage. You won't kill a 12V motor by making it work at 20V for 2 minutes, specially Maxon motors which are very well built.

Comment: But then what would you recommend to use for the voltage of the power supply which should feed the power stage? Say for a 12V or 24V nominal voltage...

Comment: This is false. Even applying nominal voltage to a motor can destroy the motor if it is overloaded, e.g. when stalling it the full 2 minutes.